# cant get EOF to exit a do while loop, with getchar()

Tags: c

I have this code

whitespaces is a type int, so I can use the getchar function

```
do
{

 ...code...

whitespaces=getchar();}
while ( whitespaces != (EOF) || whitespaces!='\n');
```

but it doesnt exit the loop when i hit CTRL+Z (i am using windows 7)

what am I doing wrong?

EDIT : thank you, all of you...! very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `||` to `&&`. Right now, if `whitespaces` is equal to `EOF`, it's not a newline, so the while condition is always true. This is presumably not what you want.

Answer (score 5):

You must use `&&` instead of `||` in the `while` condition.

Comment: hm, but why? I want it to exit the loop if I hit CTRL Z or ENTER. isnt || the OR operator?

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is incorrect:

```
while ( whitespaces != (EOF) && whitespaces!='\n');
```

A \n will automatically be different than EOF and vice-versa.